# How to get Coefficient List from an expression with various variables

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

consider following expression:

```
t = Subscript[α, 0]/2 + Subscript[α, 1]/2 + 2 Subscript[α, 2] + (9 Subscript[α, 3])/2 + 
8 Subscript[α, 4] + (25 Subscript[α, 5])/2 + 18 Subscript[α, 6] + (49 Subscript[α, 7])/2 + 
32 Subscript[α, 8] + (81 Subscript[α, 9])/2;
```

one can access variable list of expression above by using:

```
Variables[t]
```

but how can I get the corresponding coefficient list of variables? I've tried:

```
CoefficientList[t, Variables[t]]
```

it just doesn't work...

Comment: Try `CoefficientArrays`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with:

```
CoefficientList[t, Variables[t]]
```

is that it appears to create a matrix with all the cross terms.  Since you only want to first order terms, try out:

```
Coefficient[t, Variables[t], 1]
```

> ```
> {1/2, 1/2, 2, 9/2, 8, 25/2, 18, 49/2, 32, 81/2}
> ```
>
> instead.

Comment: `1` seems to be redundant.